# Java capabilities

Tags: java, macros

Does Java have anything like any of the following

- macros
- a way to iterate over all private fields
- something like smalltalk symbols-ie  something for quick comparison of static strings?

note I'm trying to emulate enums for blackckbery
(and a little worried about speed for a  simple string-> int dictionary ) which I'm fairly sure doesn't have them
please try not to include code-just references I would like to code it up myself.

Reflection seems interesting is it that difficult to use simply? can you access field names with it? can you use it with a normal blackbery java program?

Comment: that's a strange question, what do you want these things for ?

Comment: There shouldn't be a large difference in speed between a `HashMap<String, int>` and an `Enum`, though the `HashMap` will probably take more memory. Have you profiled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- What exactly do you mean by macro? If you're talking about preprocessing macros, then there is no such thing. Java doesn't have a preprocessor (but nothing stops you from using an external one in your build process).
- [Reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html#) can be used to iterate over the fields and methods of a class, but it's not really a first-class construct and meant for advanced development (usually inside a library)
- Some use of Smalltalk symbols maps pretty cleanly onto [enums](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), others do not. Note that `enum` is basically some nice syntactic sugar for the [type-safe enum pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip122.html) that can be implemented in pre-Java 5 as well.

Answer (score 3):

- No, there are no macros and I don't know of anything similar.
- You can use reflection to access any field or iterate over them.
- Not sure, but I don't think so. Strings are always objects in Java, and always have to be compared using `equals()`